# What does 表現とか感じるもの mean in this context?

Tags: grammar, syntax

The definitions for「表現」and「感じるもの」seem to take on different meanings in different sentences, I can't find which definitions are appropriate for this phrase, or if the phrase means something completely different entirely.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBqCZeOtGV8&t=0m7s

> えっと…このゼルダの伝説はですね、あのやっぱり、任天堂は常に世の中になかったものを作ると、今までなかったものを作るということをテーマにやってきていますので、えっと…同じ10年前のゼルダのテーマを引っ張ってえー、知恵と、えー、アクションを使う謎解きアドベンチャーゲームとして作っているんですけども、やっぱり、そこでの表現とか感じるものを絶対、世の中になかったものにしよう、ということでやってきました。

My translation attempt (may be completely wrong):

> With this Legend of Zelda, uhm, Nintendo has always made things that have never existed in the world before, and has done things that have never been done before, so, um ... we are drawing from ideas from the same Zelda of 10 years ago,
> and creating a mystery-solving adventure game that uses wisdom and action, but, after all, the expressions and feelings there that we came up with to use in this game is absolutely something that has never been done before.

Answer (score 1):

I think they basically refer to the same thing ("gaming experience") described from two different standpoints. Seen from the creators, it's 表現, but seen from the players, it's 感じるもの. The idea is "what we express or what players feel".

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is why I always enjoy getting someone else's perspective.